# postgresql - cumulative sum group by type and week (multiple columns)

Tags: postgresql

I want to have a cumulative sum **but** my condition needs to group by multiple columns

table: `customer`

| type | week | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01 | abc123 |
| B | 2022-01 | bcd123 |
| B | 2022-02 | efg123 |
| A | 2022-02 | klc123 |
| B | 2022-02 | mad123 |

My query now:

```
SELECT   week, type, SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY week)
FROM     (SELECT   week, type, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     customer
          GROUP BY week, type) t
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

and the results:

| week | type | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | A | 1 |
| 2022-01 | B | 1 |
| 2022-02 | A | 1 |
| 2022-02 | B | **1** |

issue is here, the last row of the result should be Sum=2, but for some reason (idk why) it follow the above.

Is it other ways to solve and calculate cumulative?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   week, type,
         SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY week, type
                        ORDER BY week
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                       )
FROM     (SELECT   week, type, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM     customer
          GROUP BY week, type) t
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Sentence "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" you can use or not, because it's default behavior.